# C# UWP MediaPlayerElement Interactive Mode Event?

Tags: c#, events, uwp

Microsoft Player Framework had an event for OnIsInteractiveChanged so we could determine if the controls were being displayed.  I can't seem to find a similar event for MediaPlayerElement.  Is there a similar event that gets fired when the controls visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> s there a similar event that gets fired when the controls visible?

Currently, there is no such event to determine if the controls were being displayed. It only provide a simple way to manage this with one new property [`ShowAndHideAutomatically`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediatransportcontrols#Methods) and two new methods `Show()` and `Hide()` .

If you do want this feature you could custom `MediaTransportControls` and create a timer to determine the controls were being displayed.

You will found [`ControlPanelFadeIn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt414180.aspx) storyboard to make the controls fade in. If control panel fade in, the `ControlPanel_ControlPanelVisibilityStates_Border` opacity will turn to 0. So 
you could create a timer to determine this value.

```
public sealed class CustomMediaTransportControls : MediaTransportControls
{
    private DispatcherTimer KeepTransportControlsVisibleTimer;
    private Border ControlPanelGrid;

    public CustomMediaTransportControls()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomMediaTransportControls);
        KeepTransportControlsVisibleTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        KeepTransportControlsVisibleTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
        KeepTransportControlsVisibleTimer.Tick += KeepTransportControlsVisibleTimer_Tick;
        KeepTransportControlsVisibleTimer.Start();
    }

    private void KeepTransportControlsVisibleTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        var opacity = ControlPanelGrid.Opacity;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(opacity);
         // do some stuff
    }  

    //overriding OnApplyTemplate
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        ControlPanelGrid = GetTemplateChild("ControlPanel_ControlPanelVisibilityStates_Border") as Border; 
        base.OnApplyTemplate();  
    }
}
```

For creatting custom transport controls, please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls).

Comment: Thank you and thanks for your sample project on using CustomMediaTransportControls.  For your YouTube resolution control, what's the best way to handle displaying which resolution is selected?  Changing the background color of the text in the MenuFlyoutItem?

Comment: Yep, you could bind selectitem with your data model.